# @Lookup method does not work with spring mvc 4.1

Tags: java, spring

I want to use the @Lookup method's annotation into the project I'm working with. The @Component is declared as follow:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class TracciatoCoperturaMondialpolManager {
//some code
}
```

And my method is declared as follow into a @Service class:

```
@Lookup
private TracciatoCoperturaMondialpolManager getTracciatoMondialpolManagerPrototype() {
    return null;
}
```

but when I call the method from the service class where is wrote, it returns null. I try even with xml as follow:

```
<bean id="tracciatoCoperturaMondialpolManager" class="it.sabacom.amministrativo.tracciati.copertura.TracciatoCoperturaMondialpolManager" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="decodificaService ----
...some xml definitions
        <lookup-method name="getTracciatoMondialpolManagerPrototype" bean="tracciatoCoperturaMondialpolManager"/>
</bean>
```

But still not working, the method continue to return null. What is going wrong? I'm using spring mvc 4.1 btw. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modifier of Lookup method must be protected or less restrictive

`<public|protected> [abstract] <return-type> theMethodName(no-arguments);`

Did you try to use this signature of method?

From [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection)